# How to handle a click event for Button that placed inside a Control Object?

Tags: c#, servercontrol

I have a control Object . In control object I have added a Button . I want to handle click event for Button object.

```
      mapcomponent.MapObjectClick += new MapComponent.MapComponent.MapObjectEventHandler(mapcomponent_MapObjectClick);

    Public void mapcomponent_MapObjectClick(object sender, MapObjectEventArg e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            var obj = sender as Control;
            var txt = obj.FindControl("txt1") as TextBox;
            if (txt != null)
                txt.Text = "hello";

            var btn = obj.FindControl("btn1") as Button;

            if (btn != null)
            {
                btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(b_Command); //handler
            }
        }
    }

 //Not working
Public void b_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
       //Want to call This Method
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `btn.OnClick`?

Answer (score 0):

You should give your button a CommandName and catch it on the OnCommand event.

```
btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(b_Command); //handler
btn.CommandName = "foo";

Public void b_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "foo")
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the point of your scenarion is, but if you want to invoke a Button click event programmatically you could use the `Button.PerformClick()` method.